# cannot posting the "matchdate" from this URL

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

cannot posting the matchdate by submit button in the form, I tried to write the following code but no output, thanks !

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "URL"

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
    res = s.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

   viewstate = soup.select_one("#__VIEWSTATE")['value']
   viewgen = soup.select_one("#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")['value']
   eventval = soup.select_one("#__EVENTVALIDATION")['value']

    payload={
        '__VIEWSTATE':viewstate,
        '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR':viewgen,
        '__EVENTVALIDATION':eventval,
        'matchdate': '2018-12-1',
        'btnSearch.x': '35',
        'btnSearch.y': '8'
    }

   req = s.post(URL,data=payload,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
   soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")
   print soup
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use selenium to input that matchdate then click on search.
This will return 6 dataframes (tables) from the html source. I'm guessing dataframe in position 4 is the one you want?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import bs4
import pandas as pd

match_date = '2018-12-1'

url = "URL"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_name("matchdate").send_keys(match_date)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='submit'][name='Submit']").click()

html = driver.page_source

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
#print (soup)

table = pd.read_html(html)
#print (table[4])

driver.close()
```

**Output:**

```
print (table[4])
          0               1   2  ...      7      8     9
0        联赛            赛事时间  状态  ...     亚盘     大小    数据
1      巴马后备  18-12-01 08:00   完  ...    NaN    NaN  析亚 欧
2      阿鲁巴联  18-12-01 08:00   完  ...    NaN    NaN  析亚 欧
3        阿甲  18-12-01 08:15   完  ...     半球      2  析亚 欧
4      新西兰联  18-12-01 09:00   完  ...   受半/一  3/3.5  析亚 欧
5      新西兰联  18-12-01 09:00   完  ...    半/一    3.5  析亚 欧
6      东亚女足  18-12-01 09:00   完  ...    NaN    NaN  析亚 欧
7       美女超  18-12-01 09:00   完  ...    NaN    NaN  析亚 欧
8      新西女超  18-12-01 09:00   完  ...    NaN    NaN  析亚 欧
9      日皇后杯  18-12-01 10:00   完  ...    NaN    NaN  析亚 欧
10     日皇后杯  18-12-01 10:00   完  ...     球半      3  析亚 欧
11   新西联U20  18-12-01 10:00   完  ...    NaN    NaN  析亚 欧
12      墨女超  18-12-01 10:00   完  ...    NaN    NaN  析亚 欧
13    中国U23  18-12-01 10:00   完  ...    NaN    NaN  析亚 欧
14      墨西丙  18-12-01 10:30   完  ...    平/半  2/2.5  析亚 欧
15      墨西丙  18-12-01 11:00   完  ...    半/一  2.5/3  析亚 欧
16      墨西丙  18-12-01 11:00   完  ...     半球    2.5  析亚 欧
17     大洋女冠  18-12-01 11:00   完  ...    NaN    NaN  析亚 欧
18     韩K联降  18-12-01 13:00   完  ...    平/半      3  析亚 欧
19     韩K联降  18-12-01 13:00   完  ...    半/一      3  析亚 欧
20     韩K联降  18-12-01 13:00   完  ...    平/半  2.5/3  析亚 欧
21      日职联  18-12-01 13:00   完  ...     平手  2.5/3  析亚 欧
22      日职联  18-12-01 13:00   完  ...     半球  2.5/3  析亚 欧
23      日职联  18-12-01 13:00   完  ...     半球      3  析亚 欧
24      日职联  18-12-01 13:00   完  ...    平/半  2.5/3  析亚 欧
25      日职联  18-12-01 13:00   完  ...    平/半    2.5  析亚 欧
26      日职联  18-12-01 13:00   完  ...    平/半  2.5/3  析亚 欧
27      日职联  18-12-01 13:00   完  ...   受平/半  2.5/3  析亚 欧
28      日职联  18-12-01 13:00   完  ...     半球    2.5  析亚 欧
29      日职联  18-12-01 13:00   完  ...    半/一  2.5/3  析亚 欧
..      ...             ...  ..  ...    ...    ...   ...
892     墨西丙  18-12-02 06:00   完  ...   受半/一    2.5  析亚 欧
893     圣尼超  18-12-02 06:00   完  ...    NaN    NaN  析亚 欧
894      阿乙  18-12-02 06:10   完  ...     半球      2  析亚 欧
895      阿甲  18-12-02 06:20   完  ...    半/一  2/2.5  析亚 欧
896    阿鲁巴联  18-12-02 06:30   完  ...    NaN    NaN  析亚 欧
897    巴拉甲秋  18-12-02 06:40   完  ...    平/半    2.5  析亚 欧
898    巴拉甲秋  18-12-02 06:40   完  ...    平/半  2/2.5  析亚 欧
899    新西女超  18-12-02 07:00   完  ...    NaN    NaN  析亚 欧
900    巴皮青杯  18-12-02 07:00   完  ...     平手    2.5  析亚 欧
901     安巴超  18-12-02 07:00   完  ...    NaN    NaN  析亚 欧
902    玻利甲秋  18-12-02 07:30   完  ...    平/半      3  析亚 欧
903    澳青联B  18-12-02 07:30   完  ...    半/一  3.5/4  析亚 欧
904     以乙北  18-12-01 20:30  腰斩  ...    NaN    NaN  析亚 欧
905     波兰乙  18-12-01 19:00  推迟  ...    NaN    NaN  析亚 欧
906    德地区西  18-12-01 21:00  推迟  ...    NaN    NaN  析亚 欧
907    德地区巴  18-12-01 21:00  推迟  ...    NaN    NaN  析亚 欧
908    德地区巴  18-12-01 21:00  推迟  ...    NaN    NaN  析亚 欧
909   丹麦U17  18-12-01 21:15  推迟  ...    NaN    NaN  析亚 欧
910      俄超  18-12-01 21:30  推迟  ...    NaN    NaN  析亚 欧
911     英议北  18-12-01 22:00  推迟  ...    NaN    NaN  析亚 欧
912      威甲  18-12-01 22:00  推迟  ...    NaN    NaN  析亚 欧
913      威甲  18-12-01 22:00  推迟  ...    NaN    NaN  析亚 欧
914      威甲  18-12-01 22:00  推迟  ...    NaN    NaN  析亚 欧
915   丹麦U17  18-12-01 22:15  推迟  ...    NaN    NaN  析亚 欧
916     英议北  18-12-01 23:00  推迟  ...    NaN    NaN  析亚 欧
917     英议南  18-12-01 23:00  推迟  ...    NaN    NaN  析亚 欧
918     英南超  18-12-01 23:00  推迟  ...    NaN    NaN  析亚 欧
919     英南超  18-12-01 23:00  推迟  ...    NaN    NaN  析亚 欧
920     尼日超  18-12-01 23:00  推迟  ...    NaN    NaN  析亚 欧
921    球会友谊  18-12-02 02:00  推迟  ...    NaN    NaN  析亚 欧

[922 rows x 10 columns]
```